# JQuery $('#submit_but2').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

Tags: javascript, jquery

Существует 2 идентичных модальных окна, внутри них формы:

```
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="submit_but">Готово</button>
```

JS:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {

          $('#submit_but').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    });
</script>
```

В первом окне данная кнопка disablиться нормально, во втором аналогичная:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="submit_but2">Готово</button> 
<script  type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    console.log($("#submit_but2").html());
    $('#submit_but2').removeAttr("disabled");
    $('#submit_but2').attr('disabled', 'disabled');


});
 </script>
```

Пробовал и то removeAttr и attr('disabled', 'disabled') всё бесполезно,
Не могу понять в чем косяк =(, как вообще понять почему не срабатывает смена атрибута.
При этом.

```
   console.log($("#submit_but2").html());
```

Даёт значения этого тега "Готово"

Comment: У Вас на странице больше чем один элемент с `id="submit_but2"` `console.log($("#submit_but2").length);`

Comment: Да нет, выдает 1

Comment: По коду вроде бы все нормально, должно работать. Посмотрите в консоль, может ошибку пишет какую-то

Comment: @VladimirLenkov это я пошутил, конечно, :). Селектор по `id` вернет обертку, содержащую не больше одного элемента.

Comment: @Igor, `console.log($("#submit_but2").length);` - тут всегда будет 1, независимо от числа элементов с этим id на странице. Чтобы увидеть нормальный результат, надо писать `console.log($("[id='submit_but2']").length)`.

Comment: Не не, тут какая то петрушка с 2-мя модалками модалки открываются ajaxom, прочему-то jquery действует на кнопку первой модалки всегда вне зависимости от ID кнопки. Т.е. если поменять их местами модалки, то будет всегда disablitsya кнопка верхней

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Id должны быть уникальны на странице.
2. Надо использовать `prop`, а не `attr`.

> ```
> $('#submit_but2').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
> ```

```
$('#submit_but2').prop("disabled", true);
```

> ```
> $('#submit_but2').removeAttr("disabled");
> ```

```
$('#submit_but2').prop("disabled", false);
```